# Python Matrix Multiplication,

Tags: python

I'm trying to create a python program to perform the strassen and regular matrix multiplication methods. However, when I try to run my strassen function with the randomly generated matrix created with the createRandom Matrix function, get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "matrixMult.py", line 106, in <module>
    print strassen(c, d, 10)
  File "matrixMult.py", line 77, in strassen
    p1 = strassen(addMatrix(a11,a22), addMatrix(b11,b22), n/2)
  File "matrixMult.py", line 78, in strassen
    p2 = strassen(addMatrix(a21,a22), b11, n/2)
  File "matrixMult.py", line 82, in strassen
    p6 = strassen(subMatrix(a21,a11), addMatrix(b11,b12), n/2)
  File "matrixMult.py", line 62, in subMatrix
    c.append(a[i][j] - b[i][j]) 
  IndexError: list index out of range
```

Here's the code. I randomly create a 10x10 matrix, then try to perform Strassen with it, and I get the preceding error. However, when I use the simple 4x4 matrices I have defined at the end, strassen works fine, and it seems my random matrices are being generated without a problem, so I'm not sure where the issue is. Anyone have any ideas?

```
import random
import time

random.seed()


def createEmptyMatrix(x, y): # create empty matrix
    matrix = [[0 for row in range(x)] for col in range(y)]
    return matrix

def createRandomMatrix(size): # create matrix filled with random ints
    matrix = []
    matrix = [[random.randint(1,20) for row in range(size)] for col in range(10)]
    return matrix

def regular(a, b): # standard O(n^3) matrix multiplication
    c = createEmptyMatrix(len(a), len(b[0]))
    for i in range(len(a)):
        for j in range(len(b[0])):
            for k in range(len(b)):
                c[i][j] += a[i][k]*b[k][j]
    return c

def split(matrix): # split matrix into quarters for strassen
    a = matrix
    b = matrix
    c = matrix
    d = matrix
    while(len(a) > len(matrix)/2):
        a = a[:len(a)/2]
        b = b[:len(b)/2]
        c = c[len(c)/2:]
        d = d[len(d)/2:]
    while(len(a[0]) > len(matrix[0])/2):
        for i in range(len(a[0])/2):
            a[i] = a[i][:len(a[i])/2]
            b[i] = b[i][len(b[i])/2:]
            c[i] = c[i][:len(c[i])/2]
            d[i] = d[i][len(d[i])/2:]
    return a,b,c,d

def addMatrix(a, b): # add 2 matrices
    d = []
    for i in range(len(a)):
        c = []
        for j in range(len(a[0])):
            c.append(a[i][j] + b[i][j])
        d.append(c)
    return d

def subMatrix(a, b): # subtract 2 matrices
    d = []
    for i in range(len(a)):
        c = []
        for j in range(len(a[0])):
            c.append(a[i][j] - b[i][j])
        d.append(c)
    return d


def strassen(a, b, n): # strassen matrix multiplication method
    #base case
    if n == 1:
        d = [[0]]
        d[0][0] = a[0][0] * b[0][0]
        return d
    else:
        a11, a12, a21, a22 = split(a)
        b11, b12, b21, b22 = split(b)

        p1 = strassen(addMatrix(a11,a22), addMatrix(b11,b22), n/2)
    p2 = strassen(addMatrix(a21,a22), b11, n/2)
    p3 = strassen(a11, subMatrix(b12,b22), n/2)
    p4 = strassen(a22, subMatrix(b21,b11), n/2)
    p5 = strassen(addMatrix(a11,a12), b22, n/2)
    p6 = strassen(subMatrix(a21,a11), addMatrix(b11,b12), n/2)
    p7 = strassen(subMatrix(a12,a22), addMatrix(b21,b22), n/2)

    c11 = addMatrix(subMatrix(addMatrix(p1, p4), p5), p7)
    c12 = addMatrix(p3, p5)
    c21 = addMatrix(p2, p4)
    c22 = addMatrix(subMatrix(addMatrix(p1, p3), p2), p6)

        c = createEmptyMatrix(len(c11)*2,len(c11)*2)

    for i in range(len(c11)):
            for j in range(len(c11)):
                c[i][j]                   = c11[i][j]
                c[i][j+len(c11)]          = c12[i][j]
                c[i+len(c11)][j]          = c21[i][j]
                c[i+len(c11)][j+len(c11)] = c22[i][j]

        return c

a = [[1,1,1,1],[2,2,2,2],[3,3,3,3],[4,4,4,4]]
b = [[5,5,5,5],[6,6,6,6],[7,7,7,7],[8,8,8,8]]
c = createRandomMatrix(10)
d = createRandomMatrix(10)
print "Strassen Outputs:"
#print strassen(c, d, 10)
print "Should be:"
print regular(c, d)
print c
print d

print a
print b
print strassen(a, b, 4)
```

Comment: It would help if you could try to find the part of your code that causes the error, and post only that function, with simple example input that still causes the same error.

Comment: consider using `numpy`?...

Comment: This code runs for me if I unindent two lines in the `strassen` function: `c = createEmptyMatrix(...` and `return c`

Comment: Strassen's algorithm for matrix multiplication only works for 2^n-by-2^n matrices.  It works for 4-by-4 because 4 is a power of 2.  If you try to use Strassen's algorithm on matrices whose size is not a power of 2, at some point along the way you'll end up attempting to add or subtract two matrices that are not of the same shape, and that will either fail or give you the wrong answer.  To use it to multiply 10x10 matrices, expand the matrix to 16-by-16 by appending six all-zero rows and columns, run the algorithm on that and remove the all-zero rows and columns afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using `numpy`, in which you can use matrices easily and all these functions already exist.

In the meantime, if you run into index errors in this function try adding something like an `assert`:

```
def subMatrix(a, b): # subtract 2 matrices
    assert len(a) == len(b), "Number of rows does not match!"
    assert len(a[0]) == len(b[0]), "Number of columns does not match!"
    d = []
    for i in range(len(a)):
        c = []
        for j in range(len(a[0])):
            c.append(a[i][j] - b[i][j])
        d.append(c)
    return d
```

However you don't need to write this function at all:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.matrix(np.random.randint(10, size=(3,3)))
b = np.matrix(np.random.randint(10, size=(3,))).T

c = a * b
d = a - b

print a
[[5 8 1]
 [7 6 1]
 [9 2 9]]

print b
[[5]
 [2]
 [4]]

print c
[[45]
 [51]
 [85]]

print d
[[ 0  3 -4]
 [ 5  4 -1]
 [ 5 -2  5]]
```

Answer (score 0):

The last line of the trackback tells you what's wrong:

```
  File "matrixMult.py", line 62, in subMatrix
    c.append(a[i][j] - b[i][j]) 
  IndexError: list index out of range
```

This line contains 4 usages of array index, one of them is out of the range of the array.

To debug this, go to line 62, add a `print i,j` just before it. You'll get lots of output and the output line just before the exception will tell you what index is out of range. This way it might be possible for you to track down the bug you have here.

"Just debug it"